# How can I use the Newspaper library for websites that need authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, python-newspaper

How can I use the Newspaper library for websites that need authentication?
I'm using the [newspaper3k](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper) library in order to download the html of several articles from different news sites (which is so far working just fine). However, as I need the full content I would need to authenticate (username, password) before requesting the html. I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction!

I assume this has to happen before I use newspaper.build() ?

(I just wanted to say at this point, this is the first time I am coding with python (or just generally coding anything) so any help at all would be great)

```
import newspaper #import newspaper library
from newspaper import news_pool

guardian = newspaper.build('https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/all', language='en', memoize_articles=True)
telegraph = newspaper.build('https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uk/', language='en', memoize_articles=True)
dagbladet = newspaper.build('https://www.svd.se/sverige', language='sv', memoize_articles=True)
dagensnyheter = newspaper.build('https://www.dn.se/nyheter/sverige/', language='sv', memoize_articles=True)

allpapers = [guardian, telegraph, dagbladet, dagensnyheter]

for papers in allpapers:
    newpathpaper = r'/Users/articles/' + today + "/" + naming #naming is just a variable from further up that gives the name of each newspaper 
    if not os.path.exists(newpathpaper):
        os.makedirs(newpathpaper)

    #parsing, downloading and creating files for articles
    pointer = 0
    while(papers.size() > pointer):
        papers_article = papers.articles[pointer]
        papers_article.download()
        if papers_article.download_state == 2: #checking if article has been downloaded
            time.sleep(2)
            papers_article.parse()
            print(papers_article.url)

            #receiving publishing date so it is comparable
            published_today = papers_article.publish_date #newspaper extractor
            published = str(published_today)[0:10] 

            #writing html
            if published == today: #today was declared earlier
                 f = open('articles/%s/%s/%s_article_%s.html' %(today, naming, naming, pointer), 'w+') #writing html file
                f.write(papers_article.html)
                print("written successfully")
                count_writes +=1
            else:
                print("not from today")

        else: 
            print("article %s" %pointer)
            print(papers_article.url)
            print("Has not downloaded!")
        pointer += 1
```

Comment: In general, on Stack Overflow, we expect you to have tried something and to show what you did, eve though it doesn't work as desired.

Comment: I added the lines of code now, stripped it down a bit though, hope it makes still sense..